# Setting up a Promise - Getting "Missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, promise, syntax-error

For the life of me, I cannot find the syntax error in this bit of code:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
promiseArray.push(
            new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                runOWSLS("Invoice", beginning2014Months[i], closing2014Months[i], "no", function (callbackResp) {
                    invoice2014Header[i] = callbackResp;
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        );
```

Comment: Questions about typos are off-topic.

Comment: This wasn't a question about a typo, it was a question about a syntax error, which @rgthree answered quite concisely.

Comment: Anyway off-topic. This question should be asked to debugger.

Comment: @KevinSouter - if your question can be answered by any linter out there, then, yes, I'd consider it a typo. It's not like you are trying to do something bizarre with the syntax, e.g., `{} == false` you are just doing `arr.push( obj; );` and wondering why it fails. The code is literally behaving as it should and as expected - a syntax error would be if it doesn't do at least one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second-to-last semi-colon:

```
promiseArray.push(
        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            runOWSLS("Invoice", beginning2014Months[i], closing2014Months[i], "no", function (callbackResp) {
                invoice2014Header[i] = callbackResp;
                resolve();
            });
        })
    );
```

Your original code was, essentially: `promiseArray.push(new Promise(););` which you can better see is incorrect on an abbreviated one-line here.

Comment: Ahh yes, that was it. Thanks for the tip!